# Дожидаться окончания не-дочернего процесса

Tags: linux, bash, процесс

Есть ли в bash встроенная функция для ожидания завершения процесса вроде `wait(pid)`, но для не-дочернего процесса?

Если нет, то каким образом можно дожидатся окончания процесса?

Интересует не механический способ проверки циклом, а что-то вроде прерываний.

Answer (score 2):

Я предполагаю, что автора интересует не произвольный процесс, а некий демон. Если этот демон "честно" создаёт pid-файл, то можно попробовать навесить inotify на удаление этого файла. Тогда, при завершении процесса демона, он будет удалять свой pid-файл, а ОС пошлёт Вам соответствующий сигнал.

Но, как очевидно, при аварийном падении демона этот фокус не пройдёт...

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен цикл ожидания, очевидно же :)

```
while [ $(pgrep $1)>'0' ] 
do
   sleep 5
done
```

Comment: автор вопроса ведь обговорил этом момент, про циклы: *Интересует **не** механический способ проверки циклом*

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно предложить скрипт, который в цикле отслеживает заданный PID и посылает вызывающему скрипту (его PID передается вторым аргументом) сигнал.

Например:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo usage: wdog.sh PID-watch PID-signal
    exit 1
fi

while [ -d /proc/$1 -a -d /proc/$2 ]
do
    sleep 1
done
[ -d /proc/$2 ] && kill -1 $2
```

И пример вызывающего скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash

I=0
trap "echo catch Sighup;I=1" SIGHUP

./wdog.sh $1 $$ &

echo read loop
while read a
do
    if [ $I == 1 ]; then
         echo end loop I=$I
         break
    fi
done
```

Следует учесть, что сигнал тут будет обработан в `read` (поскольку это встроенная команда), однако выход по прерыванию не происходит. Если же скрипт вызвал какую-либо внешнюю команду (grep, cat ...), то обработка сигнала произойдет после ее завершения.

Если воспользоваться [ответом @alexanderbarakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600360/232) (и `strace` у вас работает (по крайней мере мне в Ubuntu пришлось от рута выполнить `echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`, чтобы она заработала для отслеживания произвольного процесса с тем же UID)), то цикл ожидания в скрипте wdog.sh можно заменить на

```
strace -qe '' -p $1 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

в ответах на вопрос [WAIT for “any process” to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1058047/4827341) приведены некоторые соображения по этому поводу: какого-либо встроенного (или даже просто заведомо работоспособного) средства, конечно, нет.

у меня получилось воспользоваться программой *strace*, как предложили в [одном из ответов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22893464/4827341). манипуляций с псевдо-файловой системой `/proc` при этом не потребовалось:

```
$ strace -qe '' -p идентификатор.процесса
```

понятно, что «следить» за процессами, запущенными другими пользователями, не получится, пока не запустите *strace* от имени пользователя *root*.

Answer (score 0):

вот из [этого](http://linux.vt.tpu.ru/lab3.pdf) мануала я узнал следующее:

> Для  досрочного завершения потока можно воспользоваться функцией
>   **pthread_cancel**. Единственным аргументом этой функции является
>   идентификатор потока. Функция **pthread_cancel** возвращает 0 в случае
>   успеха и ненулевое значение(код ошибки) в случае ошибки.
>
> Функция **pthread_setcancelstate** определяет, будет  ли  поток
>   реагировать  на  обращение  к  нему  с  помощью **pthread_cancel**.

То есть получается надо отменить удаление функцией `pthread_cancel` с помощью `pthread_setcancelstate` и анализировать какие коды возвращает `pthread_cancel`, и скорей всего она будет возвращать какой то код ошибки типа поток не найден если его нет и при всем при этом она этот поток не сможет завершить.